# AppleScript Get data from log

Tags: applescript, text-files

I need my AppleScript to find some data from a log (text) and set as a value

e.g Serial ID : XXXXXX , devices : XXXXX

Also the app is generating a lot of log files, so I need to take the data from the most recent logs.

Is that even possible

```
set listOfShows to {}
set Shows to paragraphs of (read POSIX file "Users/username/Library/Logs/app/Applicationc1454545.log.log")
repeat with nextLine in Shows
    if length of nextLine is greater than 0 then
        copy nextLine to the end of listOfShows
    end if
end repeat
choose from list listOfShows/
```

Maybe I can get the file with this :

```
set sourceFolder to POSIX file "/Users/Users/Library/Logs/"

tell application "Finder"
    sort (get files of folder sourceFolder) by creation date
    -- This raises an error if the folder doesn't contain any files
    set theFile to (item 1 of result) as alias
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you sort by creation date in Finder the most recent file is the last rather than the first file.

The error occurs if there are no files and therefore no `item 1`.

Try this:

`path to library folder from user domain` is the relative path to the library folder of the current user.

```
set logFolder to (path to library folder from user domain as text) & "Logs:"
tell application "Finder" to set sortedFiles to sort (get files of folder logFolder whose name contains "Applicationc1454545") by creation date
if sortedFiles is not {} then
    set mostRecentLogFile to last item of sortedFiles as alias
    set listOfShows to {}
    set Shows to paragraphs of (read mostRecentLogFile as «class utf8»)
    repeat with nextLine in Shows
        if length of nextLine is greater than 0 then
            copy nextLine to the end of listOfShows
        end if
    end repeat
    set chosen to choose from list listOfShows
    if chose is false then return
    set chosen to item 1 of chosen
end if
```

Comment: Thank you, that's good alright, Where I'm totally lost is for grep the text and set some part of this text/log as a variable

Comment: There is the kind of data I would like to set as variable

<data1>1014821611</data1>

"DATA2" = "DATAVALUE" , however, as this is a log, this is automatically refreshed, and this can be listed a few time in the log, usually the most recent value is the good one

Comment: The SatImage.osax (Scripting Addition) provides regex search